# Android Studio not completing xml tags

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, tags

So I found another question like mine but the answers didn't solve my problem. Yesterday I updated to 3.5.0 Android studio and the xml tag auto completion is not working anymore. Example: I type Textview -and it adds automatically the basic attributes, like width and height, but the closing tag is missing. And it really slows me down.

Answer (score 1):

Your cache has been corrupted. To resolve issue try following:

1. Close Android studio completely.
2. Take backup of following folders & then delete it *(I.e. move to any other safe place. find it in your system, most probably in C: drive if using Windows)*

   ```
   <user>\.gradle\caches
   <user>\.AndroidStudio{your_version}\system\caches
   ```
3. Now start Android Studio again. It should take time to re-build cache but now it would be working fine.

Comment: didn't work. I even reinstalled my android studio from scratch. probably this update is screwed up

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `.idea` folder and all `.iml` files from the project, restarting Android Studio and rebuilding `gradle` did the trick. Autocomplete in `XML` support library is working again.

Checking out files from Version Control or copying all the source files in a new project would do the trick as well.

Comment: Ok but where are the iml files? Do i need to do this for every project?

Comment: May be previous configurations are conflicting.
Did you check if Power Save Mode on File menu is disabled? If not disable it. Then try invalidate cache and restart option. Hope it will work.